# create a .desktop launcher with unlimited stack size

Tags: .desktop

I want to create a launcher for a software that needs unlimited stack size.
If I open a terminal and run the command "ulimit -u unlimited" before running
the software it works well, but I can not create a .desktop entry for that.

Comment: Have your launcher call a `bash` script that does the `ulimit`, then calls the program.

Comment: Dear @waltinator, It does not work. I put also the command "ulimit -u unlimited" inside .profile file. When I open a terminal and check the stack by "ulimit" it prints "unlimited", but the program does not work and I need to run the command "ulimit -u unlimited" in any new terminal. It is strange.